# Обновление данных на странице, без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, freemarker

Помогите пож-та
Нужно в поле выбрать значение и чтоб в др. поле подставились его варианты, пример http://prntscr.com/qiwjwe

[image: Пример]

Думаю, что нужно делать через JavaScript, но не понимаю, как сделать так, чтоб JS соединился с базой, отправил запрос в базу и получил данные.

Использую библиотеки: Spring; Freemarker; Hibernate.

Куда копать?

Answer (score 1):

Ну с JavaScript вы угадали, только он должен отправить ajax запрос на сервер для получения вариантов для другого поля и подставить полученные значения. Т.е. вам нужно будет на сервере добавить GET метод, который будет принимать значение из первого поля и возвращать список для второго.

Краткий план как это будет работать:

1. Вы выбираете значение первого поля.
2. JavaScript отправляет ajax запрос со значением первого поля в параметре на ваш сервер.
3. Сервер получает запрос, ищет в бд нужные варианты, возвращает их.
4. JavaScript получает эти варианты и добавляет в список.